# How to configure ports on Apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, server, socket.io

I have Node JS on my server, but it does not work. I think it's a problem of wearing.

With the following command :

```
# curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
# apt-get update
# apt-get install nodejs
```

That's all, I'm not doing anything else.

---

I installed drupal nodejs :

```
# cd /home/www.mydomaine.com/public_html
# npm install drupal-node.js
# npm install pm2 -g
```

Here is the configuration of my server :

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com .php
    Action php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com /php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com
    Alias /php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com -socket /run/php/php7.1-fpm.www.mydomaine.com.sock -idle-timeout 120 -pass-header Authorization

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 138.74.184.65:80 [2001:21d0:0305:2100:0000:0000:0000:4741]:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@mydomaine.com
    ServerName mydomaine.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomaine.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost 138.74.184.65:443 [2001:21d0:0305:2100:0000:0000:0000:4741]:443>
SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/chain.pem
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCompression off
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set X-Download-Options "noopen"
    Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
    Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure

    ServerAdmin contact@mydomaine.com
    ServerName mydomaine.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomaine.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/public_html/web/

    <Directory /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/public_html/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            SetHandler php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

My site is in :

```
/home/www.mydomaine.com/public_html/web
```

Here is the NodeJS configuration for Drupal `nodejs.config.js` :

```
settings = {
  scheme: 'http',
  port: 8080,
  host: 'localhost',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: 'hgfjkliutfh',
  backend: {
    port: 443,
    host: 'www.mydomaine.com',
    scheme: 'https',
    basePath: '/web',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  debug: true,
  sslKeyPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/privkey.pem',
  sslCertPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/cert.pem',
  sslCAPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/chain.pem',
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  extensions: [],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: false,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: false,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHxhh.png)

Here is the contents of my iptables :

```
#!/bin/sh 

# Réinitialise les règles
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

# Bloque tout le trafic
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

# Autorise les connexions déjà établies et localhost
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# ICMP (Ping)
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# SSH
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4829 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 4829 -j ACCEPT

# DNS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# NTP (horloge du serveur)
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# NODE JS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

# HTTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# HTTP Caldav
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8008 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8008 -j ACCEPT

# HTTPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
# HTTPS Caldav
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8008 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT

# FTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT

# Mail SMTP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT

# Mail POP3
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Mail IMAP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT

# Anti Flood / Deni de service / scan de port
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
```

Here is the contents of my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
138.74.184.65   vps000000.ovh.net  vps000000
2001:21d0:0305:2100:0000:0000:0000:4741   vps000000.ovh.net  vps000000
127.0.1.1       myname.fr

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Here is the contents of my /etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Result of the command netstat -ntpl

```
root@vps000000:~# netstat -ntpl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2476/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4829            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1423/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10023         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1690/postgrey.pid -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1452/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24716/drupal    
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      2476/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      24939/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 :::4829                 :::*                    LISTEN      1423/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::7134                 :::*                    LISTEN      1913/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      24939/apache2
```

Drupal displays this message :

> The Node.js server was successfully reached.

On my site the following error is displayed in the console :

> Failed to load for element whose source is «
>   http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js ».

And :

> Refused to load the script
>   'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: data:
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not
>   explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

In the terminal I have :
    root@vps000000:/home/www.mydomaine.com/public_html/node_modules/drupal-node.js# node app.js
    Started http server.
    [2018/03/15 16:44:02] Route callback: checkServiceKey
    [2018/03/15 16:44:02] Route callback: healthCheck

**UPDATE**

I have updated my configuration as below and drupal seems to have found `/socket.io/socket.io.js` I started to despair.

Here is the NodeJS configuration for Drupal `nodejs.config.js` :

```
settings = {
  scheme: 'http',
  port: 8080,
  host: 'www.s1biose.com',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: 'hgfjkliutfh',
  backend: {
    port: 443,
    host: 'www.s1biose.com',
    scheme: 'https',
    basePath: '/web',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  debug: true,
  sslKeyPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.s1biose.com/privkey.pem',
  sslCertPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.s1biose.com/cert.pem',
  sslCAPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.s1biose.com/chain.pem',
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  extensions: [],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: false,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: false,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};
```

On Drupal my configuration is as follows :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDeDd.png)

Now the console displays the following message :

```
Refused to connect to 'wss://www.s1biose.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=8T6_V7vjKg48n731AAAJ' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

n.doOpen @ universalModuleDefinition:3
```

What does this message mean ? Am I on the right track ? On my previous configuration console indicated that it does not find the file `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is that sque I progress ?

What is this "wss" instead of "https" is this normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Apache you configure ports in /etc/apache2/ports.config.

In your ports.config your server is listening on port 80, however on your node settings file, you’re pointing to port 8080 and missing the backend port 80.
See step 5: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat/issues/1415624

And also, your firewall (iptables) rules are reflecting on port 8080. 
So, you need to match up port 80 or 8080.
Then try to access your site and check the Apache logs ..../ logs/Apache/access.log and 
....../error.log

Besides, your host in  in Apache and other settings files don’t match up localhost or 'www.mydomaine.com'??

Furthermore, your /etc/hosts doesn’t know about 'www.mydomaine.com' thus not reachable in your machine as it’s not in DNS.

```
 In /etc/hosts add
 127.0.0.1  mydomaine.com
```

**Updated**
Also, the refused message indicates that you need to allow .js files in your content security policy in your security.conf file or .htaccess file on shared host example:

content="default-src 'self' https:// example.com/js/"

See this example for background on the topic:
https://www.sitepoint.com/improving-web-security-with-the-content-security-policy/

**update new **

Based on your newest comments and error it’s clear that **1**) content policy isn’t changed in Apache config(see above details) and **2)** 
In your nodejs config file there is mismatch between https and backend of https(443 port).  First, try to get http working and then move to ssl. **3**) use real DNS than localhost.

Try this changes (have ** don’t add the *)

```
settings = {
  scheme: 'http',
  port: 8080,
  host: 'www.s1biose.com',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: 'hgfjkliutfh',
  backend: {
port: **80**,
host: 'www.s1biose.com',
scheme: '**http**',
basePath: '/web',
messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
```

Comment: On Firewall/iptables add a rule for port 80

Comment: Updated answer. Mark if this answers your concerns

Comment: updated the question. My problem is that I do not know how to set nodejs.config.js the backend is correct because Drupal communicates with the file. However, the file does not communicate with NodeJS

Comment: See updated answer regarding content security policy error

Comment: Thank you. The console now indicates "Blocking Mixed Active Content Upload". Here is the page of my site https://www.s1biose.com/ really need to put localhost and port 8080 in the nodejs.config.js file configuration ? It's been days that I'm trying to set nodejs on drupal and I can not do anything.

Comment: The first link in my answer has -how to configure it.  You scroll to different comments by people in that link till the end.  It has how to put hosts and ports in the config file

Comment: Also, the mixing content error maybe in related and may Warent new question. Not sure if you talking about http vs https or something in config. If your main question in answered, then mark this answer and post new focused question on the new issues

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have updated my question, I think it is progressing but I am not sure.